# recompile apk after using javadecompilers.com

Tags: apk, decompiling, smali, recompile, apktool

Is there any way to recompile the APK after decompilation using  [javadecompilers.com](http://javadecompilers.com) ? it's a nice tool to decompile APK and have java files, but i don't know how to recompile.

i tried to import the decompiled files to android studio, eclipse, Intellij IDEA CE, but there is so many errors, i solved some, but still so many that i can't solve.

i already used apktool for decompilation, but the problem is, it gives you smali files instead of java files like [javadecompilers.com](http://javadecompilers.com)

Comment: I don't know anything about javadecompilers.com, but in general, most decompilers don't produce re-compilable code, unfortunately.

Comment: As the author of one of the decompilers on that site, I can tell you that for any moderately complex program, you'll seldom, if ever, end up with output that can be round-trip compiled.  This is especially true for files that were converted from Android's bytecode format.

Answer (score 1):

you canot compile after decompile when you use tools and sites like javadecompilers.com 
the only way for compile is trying to decompile apk to assembly with apktool and modify smali file and easily compile it again (all cracker do this :))